# Debug mode in a library

Tags: java, android

I have an Android application with several "Log.d" calls along the code in order to following the events of the app.
In order to enable or disable the debug messages I call the Log with

```
 if (MyApp.debug) Log.d("Doing something");
```

Where MyApp.debug is a final boolean that I change before compiling.

Now I want to use some classes from the application as a library for another app, so I copied them into a new library project. The problem is that now in the library I have no a MyApp class.

How can I make something similar for controlling from the app if the library must print the debug messages or not?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest placing the variable inside a static class called `Log`, which you could then, at runtime, have checking a static boolean variable to figure out if it should log or not.

That way, you still have the convenience, but it's all contained inside the logger.

For example:

```
public class Log {

  public static boolean mustLog = false;

  // methods etc.
}
```

Then, in your app, just use `if(Log.mustLog) ...`

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a different custom class in your library

```
public Class LogPrefs
{
  public static final boolean enabled = true;
}
```

and set it on and off as you need. Then just

```
if (LogPrefs.enabled) Log.d("Doing something");
```

I always erase debug messages as I go, since they tend to clutter the screen. I keep however Info and Error messages; eventually they can be recovered and sent back after a crash.